# Database for record storage with revisioning

Tags: database, sqlite

I've recently been tasked with improving a records database that consists of the following:

- All records are stored in one giant
  XML file.
- Any changes or updates to
  these records are done by hand within
  this XML file.
- Each record contains
  an 'Updated' datetime stamp to keep
  some form of revision control.
- The entire XML file is also checked into
  a subversion repository to keep
  revision control for the entire
  collection.
- This records database is strictly for internal use only and does not face any public interface.

I'm a bit of a newbie to database design, but the above method feels a little cumbersome.  I was thinking of moving all of the above to some form of perhaps a SQLite database and building some form of a front end to update/remove/view entries while keeping track of any changes to that DB.  Are there better ways to do this or is it pretty standard to have a system like is already in place?

Comment: It really depends on how many programs/processes use the current format and how complex is that use. If its only one or two processes its worth cleaning up if its dozens of programs on hundreds of client machines than leave it alone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the information into a database is a good solution.  Another decent solution is just making each record its own file and using a revision-control system to track the changes to each individual record.  This is much more efficient than having one glommed-together file :-).

Comment: The putting of each record into its own file actually doesn't sound too bad.  There's probably about 4 or 5 different kinds of records, and about 200 total records, so we are not talking anything too big here.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt actually sound that bad! Depends how often its updated and how many programs read the XML.

I would try to approaches depending on the above.

First get one of the nifty XML validating editors like XML spy and define an XML Schema if or xsd if you havent already got one. You you now have a clean user interface that can update and validate the file. Continue to use the revision control to system to keep a history.

Secondly -- if the updates are really simple write a quick Java/C#/VB or whatever program to update the XML -- otherwise carry on as before.